# Sammy templates don't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, templates, sammy.js

I have this piece of code in an AJAX call:

```
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        context.render('/templates/dashboard/content/profile.template',
            {profile: response.profile}).replace($("#main-container"))
            .then(
                function(){
                $.each(response.requests,function(i,request){
                    {

                        console.log(request);
                        context.render('/templates/dashboard/content/dashboard_latest_requests.template',
                            {request:request}).appendTo($("#latest_jobs"));
                    }
                })});

    }
```

Now what happens here is that my response is an object containing an array "requests" and another object "profile". The first render works properly, as a profile template is rendered, with the correct data.
The second one, in the each loop,however, doesn't render anything. The `console.log(request)` shows that there is the proper data in the variable.

**dashboard_latest_requests**:

```
<a href="/request/ <%= request.rid %> " class="list-group-item">
    <div class="list-group-item-text clearfix">
        <div class="pull-left m-left-sm m-top-sm">
            <strong><%= request.title %></strong>
            <span class="text-muted block"><%= request.price %>$</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

The request object have all the three proprieties (rid, price and title) so the absence of them is certainly not the problem.

There is no js error shown in the console, and the `div` with the id `latest_jobs` is created when rendering the profile template.

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle with this? try in the template <% console.log(request); %> it might be that there is a higher scope variable called request that gets copied instead

Comment: you also need: then(function() {})

Comment: @memical `<%= console.log(request) %>` yields the same output as the js log